# Can selective disable on Queue consumption in @JmsListener SpringBoot possible?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I'm using SpringBoot along with @JmsListener to retrieve IBM MQ messages from multiple queues within the same QManager. So far I can get messages without any issues. But there could be scenarios, where I had to stop consuming msgs from one of these queues temporarily. It doesn't have to be dynamic.

I'm not using any custom ConnectionFactory methods. When needed, I would like to make config changes in application.properties to disable that particular Queue consumption and restart the process. Is this possible? Can't find any specific info for this scenario. Would appreciate any suggestions. TIA.

```
@Component
public class MyJmsListener {
  @JmsListener(destination = "{ibm.mq.queue.queue01}")
  public void handleQueue01(String message) {
      System.out.println("received: "+message);
  }

  @JmsListener(destination = "{ibm.mq.queue.queue02}")
  public void handleQueue02(String message) {
      System.out.println("received: "+message);
  }
} 


application.properties

ibm.mq.queue.queue01=IBM.QUEUE01
ibm.mq.queue.queue02=IBM.QUEUE02
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each `@JmsListener` an `id` property, you can start and stop them individually using the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

```
registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop();
```